# VSTS AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deploy issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I attempted to create an `automated` release pipeline on `Azure DevOps` that should build and deploy my applications to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk servers. I am using the recommended `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` Deploy task to perform this action. It works great for my .NET Core applications, but it has been putting my standard `.NET` application in a subfolder with the name `{ProjectName}_deploy` on the server.

I am using the `standard VS 2017` build with the package command set, so it is using that `zip` file created by the standard build process, but I have been unable to figure out why it wants to create a new application in a subfolder instead of placing it in the main Default Web Site folder like it does when I use the `Visual Studio deployment tool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research and attempted fixes, I discovered that the fix was to provide a manifest to AWS.

#### aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json

```xml
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "deployments": {
    "msDeploy": [
      {
        "name": "service",
        "parameters": {
          "appBundle": "CSI.Service.zip",
          "iisPath": "/"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This file must be placed within a zip hierarchy as follows:

- Zip to Upload

  - aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json
  - CSI.Service.zip (application deployment zip file from build)

### Edit: Add details about pipelines to build/deploy

For my deployment process, I use a Build Pipeline to package the project up into the zip files (multiple for some projects that use multiple instances of elastic beanstalk). After that, I run a Release Pipeline to deploy the change to Elastic Beanstalk

#### Build Pipeline

In the build pipeline, I basically build the solution, which packages the Web API into a zip file, copy the zip file and AWS manifest file to a folder together, and then zip them up into the build drop zone. It is also important to note that the name of the manifest file is important, as it must match what Amazon expects it to be. Otherwise, it will be ignored. It is also important to make sure you set the Archive task to not prepend the root folder name to the archive paths.

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln $(BuildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    clean: true

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\eb-deploy\'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\CSI.Service'
    Contents: 'aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\eb-deploy\'

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\eb-deploy\'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    Contents: CSI.Service.zip
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\eb-deploy\'

steps:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\eb-deploy\'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\eb-deploy\'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/drop/Service/eb-deploy-service-$(shared.environmentExtension).zip'
```

#### Release Pipeline

The release pipeline simply takes the created zip file from the build and pushes it up to the corresponding AWS Elastic Beanstalk application/environment.

```
steps:
- task: AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.BeanstalkDeployApplication.BeanstalkDeployApplication@1
  displayName: 'Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk: $(service.environmentName)$(shared.environmentExtension)'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'My AWS'
    regionName: 'us-east-1'
    applicationName: '$(service.applicationName)'
    environmentName: '$(service.environmentName)$(shared.environmentExtension)'
    webDeploymentArchive: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_CSI Build\drop\Service\eb-deploy-service-$(shared.environmentExtension).zip'
```

Comment: How do you integrate this extra step into your build pipeline?

Comment: @NovaDev I have added the Build and Release pipeline steps that I use for bundling and deploying the application to AWS. I used to have them together in just the build pipeline, but I moved them into 2 separate pipelines to allow me to package the solution in advance of the release. My placeholders for application name and environment name can be replaced by whatever you are using in your pipeline currently.

Comment: Thank you for this! I also had a support ticket w/ AWS and they pointed me https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-manifest.html, but they said it needs to be for ANY dotnet project, not just dotnet core.

Comment: Followup part 2: this totally worked. I had to modify a few settings, like the "$(shared.environmentExtension)" piece didn't do anything in my set up, and I don't understand the underscore in the release pipeline for _CSI Build, but basically, I got it to work. Part of what I didn't realize is that Azure can do super basic copy and zip operations, which made the rest of this make more sense.

Comment: Glad this could help you. Amazon was no help for me, either. for future reference, anything in a build pipeline with the format of `$(somename)` is a Build Variable. These were unique to my build to be able to port this build sequence between projects and re-use it with different variables for different applications/environments. The `_CSI Build` piece was just the location that the Release Pipeline used when it pulled in the drop files from my Build Pipeline.